# Expose GraphqlExceptions using spring boot starter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, graphql

When using the Spring Boot starter for graphql, all of the exceptions thrown while data fetching appear in the output console as "Internal Server Error(s) while executing query" I would like the just the `e.message()` string of the `GraphQLException` I throw to come out of the "message" part of the error field in Graphql so that the front end of this API can see what went wrong.

I've googled this to no avail. Most people expose the errors by editing the Servlet, but since I'm using the Spring Boot starter I cannot do this easily. I know that the `graphql-servlet` used by starter has a class called `DefaultGraphQLErrorHandler` found [here](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-servlet/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/servlet/DefaultGraphQLErrorHandler.java) but I do not know how to override or change it or just somehow get those errors to display.

I tried overriding the `SimpleDataFetcherExceptionHandler` in graphql, creating a CustomException that overrides GraphQlException but neither worked, the `SimpleDataFetcherExceptionHandler` implementation was never called during a debug.

I only ever see this:

[image: Graphql error output]

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

So I figured this out. I had to provide a custom implementation of a `GraphQLErrorHandler` *and* add it to the list of beans by marking as a `@Component`. I then overrided the `processErrors()` function in the error handler. When marked as a component, this bean was autowired into the graphql serverlet configurator in the graphql spring boot starter package, replacing the default one.

the `CustomGraphQlErrorHandler` I added is seen below:

```
import graphql.GraphQLError
import graphql.servlet.GenericGraphQLError
import graphql.servlet.GraphQLErrorHandler
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class CustomGraphQlErrorHandler: GraphQLErrorHandler {

    override fun processErrors(errors: MutableList<GraphQLError>?): MutableList<GraphQLError> {
        val errorList = mutableListOf<GraphQLError>()
        for(error in errors!!){
            errorList.add(GenericGraphQLError(error.message))
        }
        return errorList
    }

}
```

the output looks like this now:
[image]

Comment: Thx for your post but my GraphQErrorHandler is not called. I always get an Internal Server Error(s) while executing query. Any suggestion? Maybe you have others dependency-versions for graphql?

Comment: Similar to this approach I had a configuration class that was exposing a `@bean` implementation of `GraphQLErrorHandler`.  This was working for me until my recent upgrade attempt from `com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.2` to  `com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.4` | `5.3.1`.  There is a `5.4.1-SNAPSHOT` version that suppose to have fixed this.  I will recommend you keep an eye on the ticket [here](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/issues/171)

Comment: @Guchelkaben I am facing the similar issue. My GraphQLErrorHandler is not being called. Can I please know if you had resolved it. My Gragpql servlet version 6.x

Answer (score 6):

`SimpleDataFetcherExceptionHandler` implementation will be called when you have `graphql.servlet.exception-handlers-enabled=true` in `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Great solution works like a charm.

A more compact way of writing it in kotlin would look like this:

```
@Component
class CustomGraphQlErrorHandler : GraphQLErrorHandler {

    override fun processErrors(errors: MutableList<GraphQLError>?) =
            errors?.map { GenericGraphQLError(it.message) }?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf()

}
```

I really like the functional style of this